# Anjularjs Check checkbox based on 2 json object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new to angularjs, I'm creating a Edit & Update form for employee. I get my employee data using the following code.

```
$scope.details={};
$scope.roledata=[];
$http({url: 'someurl.php', method: "GET", params: {user_id: eid} }).then(function(response){
    $scope.roledata = $scope.details.role;
    });
```

$scope.roledata contains role assigned to employee.

Then i have made another $http for getting list of all role.

```
 $scope.commondetails={};
 $scope.roledata=[];
 $http({url: 'someurl.php', method: "GET", params: {comp_id: comp_id} }).then(function(response){
            $scope.role = $scope.commondetails.role;
            });
```

$scope.role contains the list of all role.

This is the output of both list.

1) $scope.roledata

```
{
"role": [{
    "currentrole": "approver",
    "currentroledes": "Approver"
}, {
    "currentrole": "employee",
    "currentroledes": "Employee"
}, {
    "currentrole": "hr",
    "currentroledes": "Human Resource"
}, {
    "currentrole": "mms_account_manager",
    "currentroledes": "MMS Account Manager"
}, {
    "currentrole": "salary_input_provider",
    "currentroledes": "Salary Input Provider"
}, {
    "currentrole": "support_engineer",
    "currentroledes": "support engineer"
}]
}
```

2) $scope.role

```
{
"role": [{
    "id": "0",
    "value": "Select Role"
}, {
    "id": "access_point_in-charge",
    "value": "Access point in-charge",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "approver",
    "value": "Approver",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "city_head",
    "value": "City Head",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "cost_centre_head",
    "value": "Cost centre head",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "department_head",
    "value": "Department head",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "employee",
    "value": "Employee",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "employee_without_email_id",
    "value": "Employee Without Email ID",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "hr",
    "value": "Human Resource",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "location_head",
    "value": "Location Head",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "mms_employee",
    "value": "employees not on MMP",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "office_admin",
    "value": "office administrator",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "personnel",
    "value": "Personnel",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "recruiter",
    "value": "Recruitement Officer",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "salary_input_provider",
    "value": "Salary Input Provider",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "shift _in_charge",
    "value": "Shift In-charge",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "supervisor",
    "value": "Supervisor",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "support_engineer",
    "value": "support engineer",
    "selected": "false"
}, {
    "id": "time_office",
    "value": "Time Office",
    "selected": "false"
}]
}
```

Here is my HTML.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
   <tr>
      <td valign="top" width="30%">
        <b>Current Role : </b>
      </td>
      <td width="70%">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr ng-repeat="role in roledata">
            <td>
                <b>{{role.currentroledes}}<br></b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td width="30%"  valign="top"><b>Change To :
         </b>
      </td>
      <td width="70%">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="allrole in role">
                <td>
                    <b>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allrole.id" /> 
                    <label>{{allrole.value}}</label>
                    </b>
                </td>
             </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And this is what i have on controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('RegisterCtrl',function($http,$scope,$location) {

//https calls for role and roledata.

$scope.role.forEach(function(item){
   $scope.roledata.forEach(function(savedItem){
      if(savedItem.currentroledes === item.value){
         item.selected = true;
         console.log(item);
         return true
       }
    })
});
```

I want to check those role which are assigned to employee in role list i.e in $scope.role. which i tried using the above foreach loops. but when the foreach runs the $scope.role and $scope.roledata are blank.

the problem is $scope.role and $scope.roledata are blank outside $http.get() after some googling i found out its because of asynchronous call. how to preserve the $scope outside the $http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.commondetails={}; 
$scope.details={};
$http({url: 'someurl.php', method: "GET", params: {comp_id: comp_id} }).then(function(response){
                $scope.role = $scope.commondetails.role;
                }).then(function(){
                $http({url: 'someurl.php', method: "GET", params: {user_id: eid} }).then(function(response){
                            $scope.roledata = $scope.details.role;
                            $scope.role.forEach(function(item){
                                 $scope.roledata.forEach(function(savedItem){
                                      if(savedItem.currentroledes === item.value){
                                         item.selected = true;
                                         console.log(item);
                                         return true
                                        }

                                 })
                            });
                        });
                    });
```

This is what i have done. And works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for nested async calls. Once the list of all roles is available, make a `$http` call to the fetch the role of specific user.

Through this, if `$scope.roledata == null`, there would be no iteration over the `$scope.role` to check/uncheck the role assigned.

```
$http({
    url: 'someurl.php',
    method: "GET",
    params: {
        comp_id: comp_id
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.role = $scope.commondetails.role;
    if($scope.role != null) {
        $http({
            url: 'someurl.php',
            method: "GET",
            params: {
                user_id: eid
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.roledata = $scope.details.role;
            if($scope.roledata != null) {
                $scope.role.forEach(function(item) {
                    $scope.roledata.forEach(function(savedItem) {
                        if(savedItem.currentroledes === item.value) {
                            item.selected = true;
                            console.log(item);
                            return true;
                        }
                    })
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run those **forEach** methods right after **$scope.role** and **$scope.roledata** are filled from the get async calls. You could benefit from the **promises** returned by $http and then to run the forEach method.

Take a look here:

```js
var roledataPromise = $http({url: 'someurl.php', method: "GET", params: {user_id: eid}});
var rolePromise = $http({url: 'someurl.php', method: "GET", params: {comp_id: comp_id}}); 

roledataPromise.then(function(roledataResponse){
    $scope.roledata = roledataResponse;

    rolePromise.then(function(roleResponse){
         $scope.role = roleResponse;

         //at this point you have $scope.roledata and $scope.role
         $scope.role.forEach(function(item){
           $scope.roledata.forEach(function(savedItem){
              if(savedItem.currentroledes === item.value){
                 item.selected = true;
                 console.log(item);
                 return true
               }
            })
        });

     });
 });
```

Comment: I have tried in different way. and posted my answer. Is there anyway of using service or factory for this?

Comment: You could create $resource for each data type (role, user, etc.). I think it's more readable and more flexible that way. Take a look here for more info about angular $resource and how to use it: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource